# Azure app service settings slotSetting not honored

Tags: azure-web-app-service

In Azure DevOps, in a release pipeline, I specified Application Settings to be added/update:

```
[
  {
    "name": "HOSTINGSTARTUP__KEYVAULT__CONFIGURATIONENABLED",
    "value": "true",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "HOSTINGSTARTUP__KEYVAULT__CONFIGURATIONVAULT",
    "value": "https://******.vault.azure.net",
    "slotSetting": false
  }
]
```

[image: Slotting set to false]

The slot setting is set to false. However, in the end, it becomes true after the release step happens.

[image: Slot setting set to true]

I tried deleting them and executing the release pipeline again but the `HOSTINGSTARTUP__KEYVAULT__CONFIGURATIONENABLED` slot setting flag is always set to true.

Why does this happen? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I deleted the settings and run the pipeline, the `true` value would come back.

However, after I set the "slotSetting" to false and deleted it, it started working correctly.

It seems like a bug to me but, in case you face a similar issue, do the above and it should start working again.